# 'boost::make_shared' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, make-shared

I've got the following class definition:

```
class Portal
{
   public:

   Portal( const vector<vec3> &vertices, shared_ptr<Sector> target );

   ...
};
```

Somewhere else, I want to create an instanceof said class like this:

```
auto portal = make_shared<Portal>( portalVertices, target );
```

However, I get the following error message in Visual Studio 2010:

> error C2668: 'boost::make_shared' : ambiguous call to overloaded
>   function

Can anyone tell me why? I only define a single constructor. Thank you!

Comment: It should list what the candidates are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the keyword auto I assume you are using C++11 features. 
C++11 also comes with `std::make_shared`.

So, please try adding the namespace:

```
auto portal = std::make_shared<Portal>( portalVertices, target );
```

or

```
auto portal = boost::make_shared<Portal>( portalVertices, target );
```

So what I usually do in my code / the .C file is:

```
using namespace std; // this is a "using" directive
....
void somefunction() {
    auto portal = make_shared<Portal>( ... );
}
```

As you mentioned you were specifying in your header

```
using boost::make_shared;
```

I would really like to see the full header file. As I think you actually wanted to have a using directive, but ended up in having a using declaration.

Have a look at this description:

`using` directive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

`using` declaration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: i did, to no avail. I should point out that it works just fine with other classes and that I declare the following in a common header file:

**using boost::shared_ptr;
using boost::make_shared;**

Comment: did u try removing the using boost::make_shared and then use in the code auto portal = boost::make_shared ... ?

Comment: **yeah that did it, thanks!** now, can I somehow "un-use" std::make_shared so that I don't have to specify which namespace's template to use? Also, I'm still not sure why this happens to this class but not the other +50 classes in my project. They all share the same base header.

Comment: Or, is it advisable to simly rely on MS's implementation of shared_ptr?

Comment: @Vexator: Simple: *Do not use `using namespace std;`*, especially not in a header. Typing 5 more characters is really no trouble, especially so if it saves you from such ambiguities.